# React input saves the input at first click then shows it in the UI on second click... WHY ?!!! and how to fix it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, input, rendering

I'm making a todo List App with react and i faced this kind of bug when you type in an input then click on the button to make a new todoItem object it shows an empty object then saves that input in the todoList object variable inside production code then that **first todo element appears** in the UI on **2nd click**, and on **3rd click** appears the **2nd todoItem**, **4th click 3rd element** and so forth... i don't know why is that happening and i wish to solve this, here is my code guys:

[image]

```
----------APP COMPONENT-------
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Form from "./Form";
import List from "./List";

function App() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  const [todoItem, setTodoItem] = useState({});
  const [todoList, setTodoList] = useState([]);

  const addTodoItem = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    input && setTodoItem({ content: input, id: Math.random() * 1000 });
    setTodoList([...todoList, todoItem]);
    setInput("");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Form input={input} addTodoItem={addTodoItem} setInput={setInput} />
      <List todoList={todoList} setTodoList={setTodoList} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

---------FORM COMPONENT-----------
import React from "react";

function Form({ input, setInput, addTodoItem }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <form action="">
        <label>todos</label>
        <input
          value={input}
          onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
          placeholder="what needs to be done"
          type="text"
        />
        <button onClick={addTodoItem}>set todo</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Form;


----------LIST COMPONENT-----------
import React, { useState } from "react";

function List({ setTodoList, todoList }) {
  const [completed, setCompleted] = useState(false);

  const deleteItem = (del) => {
    todoList?.map((item, i, arr) => {
      setTodoList(arr.filter((value) => value.id != del));
      console.log("item>>>", item, "index>>>>", i, "array>>>>", arr);
    });
  };
  const reverseCompleted = () =>
    completed ? setCompleted(false) : setCompleted(true);
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {todoList.map((item, i) => (
          <div key={i}>
            <p>{item.content}</p>
            <button onClick={() => deleteItem(item.id)}>Delete</button>
            <button onClick={reverseCompleted}>
              {completed ? "unCompleted" : "Completed"}
            </button>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default List;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content on the first attempt is empty, because React's `useState` update [isn't immediate](https://linguinecode.com/post/why-react-setstate-usestate-does-not-update-immediately). So you will somehow have to wait for the `todoItem` to change in order to place it in the `todoList` array.

One possible solution would be to use React's `useEffect` and track changes on the `todoItem`. And when it changes and its `content` property isn't empty, you could update the `todoList`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (todoItem.content) {
    setTodoList([...todoList, todoItem]);
  }
}, [todoItem]);

const addTodoItem = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  input && setTodoItem({ content: input, id: Math.random() * 1000 });
  setInput("");
};
```

This solution could prove to be error-prone, because whenever the `todoItem` reference changes it will be added to the `todoList`, which is not what you would want.

Another, better, solution I would advise is to declare a new variable inside the `addTodoItem` handler, and append it to the `todoList` array, as well as call `setTodoList`:

```
const addTodoItem = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const newTodoItem = { content: input, id: Math.random() * 1000 };
  input && setTodoItem(newTodoItem);
  setTodoList([...todoList, newTodoItem]);
  setInput("");
};
```

Comment: but one thing i didn't understand is why you are making a variable the newTodItem why not directly setTodoItem({ content: input, id: Math.random() * 1000 }) what's the difference isn't the same thing ? @Kapobajza

Comment: @MansouriAla I am declaring the variable `newTodoItem` because you can instantly use its updated value in two functions: `setTodoItem` and `setTodoList`. Whereas if you used the `todoItem` variable, you have to wait for its value to be updated by the `setTodoItem` `useState` hook, before using it. `input && setTodoItem({ content: input, id: Math.random() * 1000 });` after this line is executed, `todoItem`'s value is still an empty object, `{}`. So when the next line executes: `setTodoList([...todoList, todoItem]);`, it sets an empty object in the array.

Comment: Yeah i see now i remember that useState doesn't execute instantly so the next value will take an empty object thank you so much for the explanation appreciate it i understand now